# USB Wifi adapter not working/showing up on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, pi-zero, wireless-adapter, realtek

My usb wifi adapter is not working on my raspberry pi zero. PS: Im new to Linux.

The adapter is called "Realtek RLT8192EU 802.11n Network Adapter".
The adapter works fine on windows 10 but not on Linux. According to the manual I have to install the drivers for it to work on linux. I tried this but I got some errors ->

```
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=armv6l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.14.69+/build M=/home/pi/Downloads/wifi_driver/Driver/linux/driver/rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.14_134 55.20150212_BTCOEX20150128-51 
modules make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.14.69+/build: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog.  
Stop.
Makefile:1551: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

When I type "Mesg" this is the result:

```
is y
```

Here is the output when I type "lsusb":

```
    Edit: Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1532:0037 Razer USA, Ltd 
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:07f8 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 600 (model 1576)
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is the output when I type "uname -a":

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.69+ #1141 Mon Sep 10 15:13:50 BST 2018 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Here are the drivers I tried to install but that didn't work: [Drivers (kjell.com)](https://www.kjell.com/se/sortiment/dator-natverk/natverk/tradlost-natverk/tradlosa-natverkskort/plexgear-tradlost-usb-natverkskort-300-mb-s-p61343). This is the website where I bought the usb adapter from aswell.

-Thanks :)

EDIT: I read somewhere that using a powered usb-hub could solve the problem. Considering my current usb-hub is kinda low-quality (cheap), would it be a good idea to buy a new one?

Comment: Next troubleshooting step would be "ip -s link"  to check all you network devices

Comment: ip -s link only shows lo and eth0

Comment: Thus you verified what is already known - the OS does not recognize the adapter. But USB found it.Back to the driver .Just for drill - you did verify WiFi is enabled in raspi-config.

Comment: "PS: Im new to Linux" ALWAYS run "sudo apt update  upgrade "to make sure you are not fighting  windmills.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I actually re-installed respbian. Now it looks different when I run the "lsusb" command. I edited the orignal post. When trying to enable wifi trough raspi-config I get the error "no interface found" and "There was an error running option N2 Wi-Fi"

Comment: The driver should be in the repo as `firmware-realtek` ... is it installed?  `sudo apt file --installed |grep firmware-realtek`

Comment: I got the error "--installed is not understood in combination with the other options"

Comment: Ok, now the wifi adapter shows up when doing "lsusb" and "lsmod", but it still says "no wifi interface found" when clicking on the wifi icon. I read online that using a powered hub may help, should I try this aswell? Or is it something else? Would the adapter even be detected if the usb hub was the problem? Thanks

Comment: `sudo apt list --installed | grep realtek` will tell you if the firmware is installed or not. If it's not then try `sudo apt update && sudo apt install firmware-realtek`

Comment: `I tried this but I got some errors` ... what errors?

Comment: I'm not home right now, but I think this was the error: "Warning, 2 errors found. Do mesg to check error". I then typed mesg and the result was "is y". I can double check when I get home, but I think that was what I got.

Comment: I updated the question now.

Comment: @KennetRunner I ran that command and this is the result: firmware-realtek/stable,now 1:20161130-3+rpt4 all [installed]

Comment: "powered usb-hub could solve the problem" On RPi Zero the USB connector is wired directly to USB power connector hence whatever the capacity (A) of +5V source is that is how much power you can draw on the USB bus. Of course there should be a (practical) limit so the Zero PCB trace does not became one time fuse.

Comment: Finally! After installing some drivers and fixing some errors it finally works! (How I got it working is explained in the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I got it working:

EDIT: I re-installed raspbian stretch. I skipped the updates and I am currently using 4.14.50+.

First I followed this tutorial: https://askubuntu.com/a/863433

But when I tried to run the "make" command I got an error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-rpi-3.6.y'
Makefile:564: /usr/src/linux-rpi-3.6.y/arch/armv6l/Makefile: No such file or directory
```

Executing these commands magically fixed that for me:

```
cd /usr/src/linux-rpi-3.6.y/arch/
sudo ln -s arm armv6l
```

When I tried to run the modprobe command I also got an error that my module was not found. I just had to reboot and now it finally works (I did not use the modprobe command).

Comment: for me, it was "ln -s arm armv7l", but did the trick. Thank you!